# .Net Core and Azure AD B2C Setup

Tags: azure, authentication, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a tutorial or setup guide for setting up Azure AD B2C in .Net Core? The [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) provided by the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) is very outdated and doesn't have much explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not mutch you have to configure on your ASP.NET core application. The main part (beside configure your AAD B2C) is to add / set the authentication middleware to use jwt bearer and pass your tenant / policy to it.

[Tutorial link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi/).

Example configuration (taken from the tutorial):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  { 
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
  {
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft just released some new docs on ASP.NET Core:

- [Cloud authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c)
- [Cloud authentication in web APIs with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi)